# Transfer data between two angular apps in nx workspace

Tags: angular, data-transfer, nx-workspace

Is it possible to transfer data between two angular apps in a nx-workspace

We can share data between libraries by using a shared-library. I tried to create two angular apps in a nx-workspace and i am trying to share data between them..

Comment: Question is unclear, transfer/share data isn’t a description of a problem

Comment: @AndrewAllen - I need to transfer a value, lets say 'Hello world' on button click, from one app to another in nx-workspace.. I have two apps (app1, app2), on any event trigger i need to pass a value from app1 to app2..

Comment: As Andrew said, it's very unclear. Do you need to reuse a variable between different libs? or are we talking about 2 apps communicating at runtime with each others (either through tab sync mechanism, or server for example)

Comment: I think you're misusing apps. Apps don't share data, they're run in the user's browser. Do you want to place static data in a library and then have both apps use that library?

Comment: @maxime1992 - Yes..I am talking about 2 apps communicating at runtime with each other. Assume a form in app1, clicking on Submit button the entire form data should be passed to app2. How can we achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

When you're talking about two different Angular applications running separately in the browser, they can't directly share data through services because they're different instances running in the browser.

Are these two app served from the same domain?

If so you could used localStorage or seassionStorage.

```
// In app1
localStorage.setItem('formData', JSON.stringify(data));

// In app2
const formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
```

Btw: I would use NGRX or NGXS for state management. I mostly prefer NGXS.

Otherwise you need to create server-side comunication.

One application could communicate using an HTTP request, while the other application listens and retrieves the data using WebSockets.

Comment: if you use NGRX in nx workspace project you can pass data between apps ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are running 2 different nx apps, you cannot share data. They are two different environments. To share data you either need to do through server (maybe websockets if you need realtime).
If it's same domain, you could use localStorage but I am pretty sure you can't listen for changes to localstorage realtime.
Also depends on if you are running apps as seperate environments, because you could use microfrontend approach where you have multiple apps but its same environment in browser (tab/window). In this case you could share data because both apps would have same window object. You could also setup redux or similar data store that can be used as communication between the two. But this is under assumption that both apps run in same page.
There is no much cases where you want microfrontend approach because libs approach is enough seperation in most cases. One reason would be if you have multiple MS and each wants to host their own part of "frontend" instead of having one place from where you serve whole frontend.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).